# Measuring the adoption of a concept in a company

Tags: company-culture

At my company our new executive has put in place a new concept for operational excellence and would like it to become the new way of life, the structure that defines the working culture. My question is then: what are the best-practices to measure the dispersion and/or the adoption of the concept within an organization in the short term and long term realms?

Emailed Surveys? Free-response boxes? Formal evaluation against the concept's key standards on mid-year reviews? Gamification? What has worked for you?

The company is too large to sustain collection techniques that require extensive manual moderation for an extended period of time so automation in the data collection process is a plus.

Comment: *automation in the data collection process is a plus*. If you don't tell use **what** there is to measure (*a new concept for operational excellence* is not measurable) this question just asks for a list of options and is therefore too broad.

Comment: **And** your question comes too late. The moment this *new concept* was introduced was the time to define measurable quantities. Failing to do so shows that your executive and/or your company is willing to throw a lot of time/money away not caring how to measure the effectiveness.

Answer (score 2):

How to measure depends entirely on what the change actually was. You need a baseline measurement of performance **before the change** and then continue to measure after the change.

But what defines performance is directly associated to what the change was. Some changes are harder to measure than others. It is relatively simple to measure how many people in an organization have starting using the new Project management software. It is harder to measure how many people are being kinder to fellow employees.

Some measurement techniques include:

- Keystroke recorders
- Counts of widgits completed
- Counts of items backlogged
- Surveys (Hard to design one that is statistically accurate and peoplw will lie on these at work especially if they don't trust that it is anonymous)
- Retention rates
- Cost over time (before and after the change, such as a change that is supposed to lower energy costs)

If you really want to learn how to measure such things, do some in depth reading on quality measurement. The American Society for Quality has a lot of good resources. Also look into six sigma techniques and Total Quality Management.

Any management that decides on a new "concept for operational excellence" without taking the time to define and measure current performance indicators before implementing the change is simply not serious about the change or incompetent.

And incidentally if you want those measures to be valid for measuring organizational change, they must not ever be used to measure individual performance. You need to read W. Edwards Deming to understand why.

Comment: HLGEM I think you are making it too complicated.  You just count how many excellences your operation has produced each week.  Easy as pie.

Comment: @Myles Why bother counting anything?  Just let confirmation bias give people the answer they are expecting through casual observation.

Comment: @HLGEM Can you add a link to Deming?